# Проблема с передачей аргументов в приложение через cmd

Tags: windows

Есть ярлык, который запускает exe файл, при этом передает в него параметр `NoCheckVersion`. В ярлыке в пункте "объект" находится следующее - `"D:\Runes of Magic\Client.exe" NoCheckVersion`. Пытаюсь запустить этот же exe, но уже с командной строки, пишу `Client.exe NoCheckVersion`, но приложение запускается так, будто в него ничего и не передавали.

Полностью копировал текст, что находится в ярлык в пункте "объект", - результат тот же. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может `NoCheckVersion` надо в кавычки взять?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает